# System won't shutdown unless I stop networking init script

Tags: 12.04, networking, power-management, freeze, upstart

I speculate it's networking related since I could only shut down my system if I do `/etc/init.d/networking stop` first. If I tried to put the system to sleep, it disconnect the network then reconnect it automatically, never goes to sleep. I uninstalled the network manager, then `/etc/init.d/networking stop` will not help shutdown the system anymore.

When I boot into the OS, there were some warning about Unknown job:S20acpid,S20network-interface, S20network-manager:

[image]

I got some advices to do `update-rc.d -f` to remove all those script, which I am not certain if it's right thing to do. The messages are gone but the problem remains.

When I tried to restart, I used to get this message:

[image]

It doesn't seem to be the modem manager since I later removed it.

Once upon a time, the froze shutting down/restarting can be restarted when I presses Ctrl+Alt+Delete, and it says something like networking is stopped externally.
If I log in single user mode, and shutdown or reboot, it show this screen

[image]

I also tried `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "acpi=force"`

This is a Ubuntu 12.04 running on Thinkpad T520, not new installation, no such problems occurred before.